# Show lodar on instead of error code on jw player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer

I am using jw player in my react project. I need to show lodar whenever I get the below error.

```
  const playVideoAfterCOmplete = () => {
    if (liveTime >= 0) {
      setCopyLiveUrl(liveVideoUrl);
      setLiveVideoUrl("");
    }
  };
<ReactJWPlayer
  playerId="JwPlayer"
  playerScript="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/libraries/xxxxyyy.js"
  file={liveVideoUrl.replace("index.m3u8", "index_360p.m3u8")}
  onTime={(e) => {
    $("#timer_span").text(
      `${new Date(e.currentTime * 1000).toISOString().substring(11, 23)}`
    );
    setLiveTime(e.currentTime);
  }}
  id="jwplayer"
  onError={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.jwplayer().load({ file:"https://acbd.com", image:"http://blog.com/streamimage-error.png" });
    errorArray.includes(e.code) ? playVideoAfterCOmplete() : console.log(e);
  }}
/>;
```

[image]